What does "効果" here mean? I don't get it
彼と自分の力は多分、日向のようにわかりやすく対峙はしない。
親和性があり、だからといって効果が低減するような組み合わせでもないだろう。
The character is thinking of fighting his enemy. In the first line he comment that unlike with  Hinata, with his and the other's strength/powers, where it's easy to understand.
親和性があり、だからといって is "we have an affinity, but still..." What does "効果が低減する" here mean?

効果 refers to the effects of the skills of "he" and "I" (彼と自分の力). In battle-related contexts, 親和性 ("affinity") is used to describe a positive synergy, such as when one character's defense-lowering skill enhances another character's melee attacks.
However, this text seems slightly odd in two ways to me:

Saying 効果が低減する means the author also has "negative synergy" or "anti-synergy" in mind, but 親和性 is usually not used to describe this.

対峙する normally means "to confront (face to face)", but in this context, it seems to be used like "to conflict". The normal verb in this context is 対立する.


Anyway, the translation is as follows:

彼と自分の力は多分、日向のようにわかりやすく対峙はしない。親和性があり、だからといって効果が低減するような組み合わせでもないだろう。
Our skills probably won't be in such clear conflict like in Hinata's case. They have good affinity/synergy, and this doesn't mean that this combination reduces their effectiveness, either.


本筋とは関係ないですが、私は「日向のように」を unlike の意味に取ってました。たしかにlike とも読める、おもしろい...

@rk03 "Unlike with Hinata, ..." のようにも訳せると思います。というか、なるべく直訳に近づけたいということでなければそっちのほうが自然かも…
